# Building and storing complex SQL query for later editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel, rails-postgresql, hstore

I am using Rails 3.2.8 to build a "product set" builder that mirrors Google Analytics' Custom Profile builder. For example, a user may define a product set as follows:

(Category = 'Printers') and ((Name contains 'Wireless') or (Name contains 'Wifi'))

My product data is stored in Postgres (9.1.4) using an HStore column to store the dynamic product attributes. I have built a form that can construct the query using Arel but am stuck on the following requirements:
1. The query must be serialized to the database. I can store the .to_sql string but am then stuck with...
2. I must be able to reconstruct the user's form for later editing, as these are not one-time searches but rather shared queries.

How can I serialize in such a way that I can easily reconstruct the user defined query?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just serialize the parameters that rails gets from the form?

You'd have a hash with the keys and values from the user inputted form, and could easily feed it back into whatever logic you use to query the database from said form, or further process it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have persistent model for saving the user's options about the search.
2. When you need to run the query, you will get the user's saved options and will pass them to custom method that use `ransacker`. You can access values in the `hstore` like this:

```rb
Arel::Node::InfixOperator.new('->>', 'hstore_column_name', Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new('key_in_hstore'))
```